# Parrot Rebus redux

Tags: rebus

[image]

This is a slightly modified thing I remember from a line drawing in a book years ago.  Well-known phrase.

Hint

> *Most* of the word Gangsta is a red herring.  This rebus predates rap as we know it.

another hint

> One "bird" is *the best*, and he's standing on a couple of letters.

Comment: A song by Coolio comes to mind...

Comment: They been spending most their lives living in the gangsta's paradise.. But I'm pretty sure those are lorikeets

Comment: That hint should remove any rappy ideas.  @Raystafarian You're right about them not being actual parrots, but it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Aww.. but "parrot"ise! Heh.

Comment: @IanMacDonald Haha, yeah, I didn't consider that.  May have been subconscious!

Comment: They must be discussing their pecking order..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

it's

> Honesty is the best policy

Because

> on ST is the best Polly, see?

Comment: Yup you got it!  well done.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't it, but still sort of fun because it works:

> Pollyanna

Because it's

> Polly on a (should be little further right, but still close)